# Does quantum entanglement necessitate that two particles communicate their state with one another?

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light, non-locality, pair-production

I often hear it said that quantum particles, like an electron-positron pair or two entangled photons, which are entangled with one another communicate or transfer information about their state instantaneously over long distances in such a way that they are guaranteed to be in particular configurations simultaneously.

In the example of the electron-positron pair, their spins are the negative of each other whenever measured. Is it necessary that they are communicating this information from one to the other, or that they just share a local random number generator?

You could make a series of similar measurements of this kind where you measure the second particle at varying times after the first, and note that they are 100% of the time in the opposite direction of the other, and do not evolve in time and are rather trapped in that state by the observation. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that for an electron-positron pair, the spins are not entangled. You can do spin measurements on both particles but these spins will not show any correlation. Only for two indistinguishable fermions, this correlation will show up, and this can be a +- as well as a -- combination, depending on where the entanglement took place.
The point is that the entanglement turns the two (or more) states into a single state. It is this state that is measured and collapses into whatever it is built from. In the case of electron spins, this can be a ++ (--) or a +- (-+) state. So the individual spin states don't exist (yet). Upon measurement, the entanglement is broken and both spin states exist separately. There is no new entangled state that evolves again, only two separate states.

Answer (score 1):

Entanglement is a complicated way to say that there exists a quantum mechanical wave function describing the probabilities of finding the entangled particles. The electron positron production wavefunction has entanglement of the electron and positron, but because it [needs a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section) in order for the photon to create the pair, spin can be exchanged with the field and thus cannot be a useful quantum number in seeing the correlation macroscopically.

[image: pairprod]

Charge is a good quantum number to see entanglement: no matter how far apart the pair goes in space, if you measure an electron, you know the other particle is a positron.

In the case of a $π^0$ decay to two gamma, spin also is  good quantum number, because the $π^0$ has spin zero, so if you measure one gamma to have spin up, the other has to have spin down.

> Is it necessary that they are communicating this information from one to the other, or that they just share a local random number generator?

The information is in the wavefunction, which is not random but a solution to a quantum mechanical differential equation.

> You could make a series of similar measurements of this kind where you measure the second particle at varying times after the first,

In quantum mechanics, measurements involve the need of a new solution to quantum mechanical equations, so what you envisage is not doable. Except in special irrelevant conditions. For example when you detect the particles in a bubble chamber. You can take any increment and decide on the charge of the particle.

> Does quantum entanglement necessitate that two particles communicate their state with one another?

No. The information is in the original wavefunction describing the two particles before they go apart.

It is just logic, the same exists in everyday life: If you know an identical twin pair and are told one of them is going to be working in Japan, when you meet in town the brother, you know who is in Japan without information transfer, the information is in your head data bank.

Comment: Not the answer that the disciples of the pure doctrine accept. but it is logical and I like it. +1

Comment: The trouble with all these answers on entanglement is that they state the obvious, that if you measure one you can expect the other one to be its conjugate.   The question is "so what?".  We know the superposition does not identify the state of an individual particle, but we do know that once we measure it will be the conjugate - which is pretty obvious.   Now I assume the act of measuring must change the wavefunction and that is the point of the instant communication problem, if this is so, then I have never heard a clear exposition of this.

Comment: @Alexander  the "instant" happens in the observer's brain , who makes the logical conclusions

Comment: @anna v I thought the point was, yes we know the other particle will be the conjugate, but this is true which ever orientation you choose to measure spin (for example) and that information can be unavailable until the particles have separated.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Copenhagen interpretation, a couple of entangled particles were separated from each other for a long distance. If we measure one of the entangled particles, its direction is up, then the other's direction is down simultaneously, and vice versa. However, before the measurement, the couple of entangled particles haven't direction anymore, no up and no down. In a manner of speaking, measurement creates up or down direction, the couple entangled particles have opposite directions simultaneously, and there is no communication between them. It is a natural law that nature tells us, but no one knows why this is so.