# Can you entangle two already existing particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Can you entangle two already existing particles? or do you have to "create" entangled particles from "scratch"? if so, how would one do this? (say, entangle two already existing electrons).

Edit: Better example of what I'm asking, lets say I had an electron in a block of gold and then an electron in a block of silver I could entangle them and use each electron to manipulate each other?

Comment: Whenever you let an environment interact with your system, the two get entangled, but nothing is (necessarily) getting created. A special case of this is 'measuring' your system.

Answer (score 5):

Any interaction between two systems will typically lead to entanglement.  If $\vert \phi_1\rangle$ and $\vert \psi_2\rangle$ are eigenstates of $H_1$ and $H_2$ respectively, then an interaction term $V_{12}$ will usually be so that the eigenstates of
\begin{align}
H=H_1+H_2+V_{12}
\end{align}
are not of the form $\vert\chi_{12}\rangle =\vert\phi_1\rangle\vert\psi_2\rangle$ but rather of the form
\begin{align}
\vert\chi_{12}\rangle =\sum_{ij}c_{ij}\vert\phi_i\rangle\vert\psi_i\rangle\, .
\end{align}
Loosely speaking, suppose
\begin{align}
H\vert\phi_1\rangle\vert\psi_2\rangle
&=(H_1+H_2+V_{12})\vert\phi_1\rangle\vert\psi_2\rangle\, ,\\
&=(E_1+E_2)\vert\phi_1\rangle\vert\psi_2\rangle
+\sum_{ij}\vert\phi_i\rangle \vert\psi_j\rangle\langle \phi_i;\psi_j\vert 
V_{12}\vert\phi_1;\psi_2\rangle\, .
\end{align}
Unless $\langle \phi_i;\psi_j\vert 
V_{12}\vert\phi_1;\psi_2\rangle$ is proportional to $\left(\sum_{i}c_i\vert\phi_i\rangle\right)\vert\psi_2\rangle$, the result will not be a separable state.  But if $V_{12}$ gives such a linear combination, there is no interaction with the 2nd system as it has remained undisturbed by $V_{12}$.

This is not a rigorous argument but it does give insight into how entanglement typically results from interactions.

Comment: But it still comes down to simply correlating the movement of two objects so that after sending them on their way you could later measure one and know something about the other. It takes precise effort to do this. You cannot simply smash two particles together and hope they become correlated.

Comment: @BillAlsept that is incorrect, it is hard to avoid correlation, it is not hard to create correlation. Of course, it is hard to create correlation *of a very particular nature*; maybe that is what you are thinking of?

Comment: @RubenVerresen if the two objects are not perfectly correlated then what kind of measurement can you make after that?

Comment: @BillAlsept I'm not sure I understand the trust of your comment.  Entanglement is synonymous with no-separable: that's all that's needed.  There is no notion of perfect correlation, or post-measurements here: those are issues separate to entanglement itself.   Maybe you can expand on what you have in mind when you bring the idea of "perfect correlation" into the debate?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero OK, I understand when the motions of two objects are physically correlated. This would include trajectories, speed, spin or polarization, oscillations if there’s frequencies involved and very precise detection both linear and target location. My questions to you would be (1) How do you know when two objects are entangled? (2) What physically confirms that? (3) how is it different than correlation?

Comment: @BillAlsept you know that two objects are entangled when the density matrix for the system is non-separable.  To check that is not necessarily easy in general but for a pair of 2-level systems you can use the [Peres-Horodecki criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion).  You’d have to reconstruct the density matrix using tomography first.

Comment: @BillAlsept I do not quite know what you mean by “what physically confirms that?”. I’m not an expert at detecting entanglement but there are [entanglement witnesses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_witness) that take the form of inequalities so that, when violated, you are guaranteed to have entanglement.  *Stronger-than-classical* correlations are the hallmark of entanglement (*viz* Bell experiments); the correlation business depends on precise definitions of correlations, and of course on excluding explanation in terms of classical correlation to guarantee entanglement.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero i’m not sure what that means. What I know is they claim the predictions of quantum mechanics cannot be classically reproduced. Therefore something special (and incomplete) called entanglement is needed to try and explain what’s not understood. You don’t need the complicated things mentioned above, just stick with a simple experiment like multiple polarizers. cos2theta can be explained physically without something called entanglement.

Comment: @BillAlsept I’m not sure I follow, and the asynchronous format doesn’t help.  I’m willing to continue in chat if you are but later in the week as I have some urgent things to finish before tomorrow morning and I don’t want to spend all night in these.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yes thanks, I will be traveling this week but I can still take time. Always love discussing the stuff.

Comment: I think the answer in <3> (@BillAlsept) is exactly correct: the interaction piece; $\langle\varphi_i;\psi_j|V_{12}|\varphi_1;\psi_2\rangle$ is such that it leaves a non-separable two-state wavefunction: $|\chi_{12}⟩=\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}|\varphi_i⟩|\psi_i⟩$.

Comment: My question is; can someone give specific examples of such interactions or a class of interactions that don't involve spontaneous creation? For example, we know pair creation of an e+e- pair from a gamma is such an interaction (entangling), but is Compton scattering? I don't think Compton scattering is (does not result in a two-particle wavefunction). Can anyone give an example interaction that does not involve spontaneous pair creation that results in a two-particle state?

Answer (score 4):

All scattering experiments of high energy physics start with the scattering of two particles. At the point of interacion there exists a quantum mechanical wavefunction describing mathematically the interaction, and all particles coming out of the interaction are by definition "entangled" by conservations laws and quantum number conservations. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645870/does-quantum-entanglement-necessitate-that-two-particles-communicate-their-state/645902#645902) of mine..

Comment: Yes but technically aren’t you just trying to correlate the two?

Comment: @BillAlsept In scattering experiments one is studying the quantum mechanical interaction between  particles, that is the whole point of the experiment. What is called entanglement, the usual spin correlations are a tiny part of the knowledge of the interactions gained by the experiment.

Comment: Scattering two particles is a physical action. In the controlled experiment what are you physically doing to each particle.

Comment: @BillAlsept  making them meet at a "point"

Comment: Yes but after you bring them together what are you physically trying to make each one do so that you can measure them later? If you have one ball sitting on a table and smash another one into it they’ll come together but after that they will not be doing the same thing.

Comment: @BillAlsept  the outgoing particles, if they are just two, will be part of the accumulation  of events needed to measure the crossection of two to two scattering. If more outgoing new reactions are to be studied, again after accumulation to get the crossection (connected to the quantum mechanical probability )

Comment: yes but that’s over complicating what EPR intended. The point was to correlate two particles so that later you can measure one of them a certain way and know something about the other without affecting it. You could then precisely correlate the motion of two objects so that when later measured they will reproduce the results of quantum mechanics or Malus law.

Comment: @BillAlsept  but you can do that, with ee to ee scattering and the spins before and after

Comment: are you talking about Stern Gerlach experiments?

Comment: @BillAlsept, no, I am talking of a single  electron on a single electron-scattering experiment with known polarization of the incoming electrons.  then the two outgoing electrons will have a polarization, and measuring one gives you also the polarization of the other, spin entanglement.

Comment: so isn’t that correlation or anti-correlation? @annav

Comment: @BillAlsept  the fashion is to call it entanglement

Comment: yes I understand and my very first comment was only pointing out that is the same as correlating.